# Why is the extension of my Swift class not visible outside the defining file?

Tags: ios, swift, visibility, nsmanagedobject

I have an Xcode-generated NSManagedObject class for my CoreData model.

```
@objc(SomeClass) class SomeClass : NSManagedObject { /* ... */ }
```

It is defined in a file named 'SomeClass.swift'. I would like to extend this class, so I created 'SomeClassExtension.swift'. I define the extension like this:

```
extension SomeClass {
    class func typeMethod1() {}
    func instanceMethod2() {}
}
```

These extension methods can be used within this defining file, but they are not visible outside of it. What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 69):

It sounds like your new file (SomeClassExtension.swift) didn't get included in the correct target. Double-check the file's target membership by selecting the file in Xcode, then opening the "File Inspector" (View menu > Utilities > Show File Inspector). Make sure the correct targets are checked under the **Target Membership** heading.

Comment: I ended up unchecking the target and rechecking it. That fixed it for me.

Comment: Did anybody figure out what the issue was?

Comment: I'm getting the same error, however my app compiles just find with the error as it just go away during compilation. Very odd and annoying (Xcode 7.1.1).

Comment: Weird; must be an indexing issue; after calling one of the functions in the extension from the AppDelegate, the error went away the other places the functions were used - I can now dot-access them from anywhere.

Comment: This is a very useful solution. To me the issue was generated by solving a conflict in the versioning system. Merging two files, it happened mine was not included in the main target.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any public modifiers on those methods.

Comment: Everything in Swift is "internal" by default, so declarations in one file should be visible to code in another as long as they're part of the same build target.

Comment: Yeah that's actually a fair point. If everything is in the same target, that is.

Comment: @NateCook Hi, Nate. So is there a way to hide definition and implementation details (for both `var`s ad methods) in Swift like one could do in Objective-C by putting things only in .m files? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig Swift has file- and module-based access control with `public`, `internal`, and `private` modifiers, a very different approach than header files. You can read more in the [Swift Language book](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html).

Comment: @NateCook Right; I remembered that after posting the question. I was too tired as I asked. Many thanks for replying.

Comment: @EnricoGranata: This bit me.  Thank you.  I had built a giant pile of tests and started including the source in the test target.  This actually worked fine for quite a ways in.  But eventually, I had to import the app project.  Making the testable object public should have been my first answer.